# Execute the last thread of ThreadPool only

Tags: c#, threadpool, task-parallel-library

I am creating an auto-complete control that updates as the user types text. Every time the user types a key a new thread fires in order to filter the results. The results come over the network and are a lot therefore it takes about 1 minute to filter. This is something similar of what I have:

```
    object _lock = new object();
    volatile static bool isThreadRunning=false ;
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        var text = textBox1.Text.ToUpper();
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
        {

            lock (_lock) // avoid multiple threads to be running at the same time
            {
                isThreadRunning = true;

                // do work in here

                isThreadRunning=false;
            }

        },text);
    }
```

So as you can see if I where to quickly type "Hello" then 5 threads will be created and 4 of them will have to wait for the first one to finish. Once that thread finishes the next one will continue to execute and so on.

If there exists 4 threads waiting to execute I will like to only execute the last one. Also the threads enter the lock in random order. How could I determine which is the last one. If a new thread fires and a thread is currently executing maybe I could cancel that thread somehow and that way the order will always be correct. How can I implement that algorithm?

---

### EDIT

This is what I have worked out:

```
    class DoWorkOnce
    {

        static object _lock = new object();
        static Stack<Action> Work = new Stack<Action>();

        public static void Add(Action task)
        {
            Work.Push(task);
            DoSomeWork();                
        }

        private static void DoSomeWork()
        {                
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                lock (_lock) // ensure that the following block of code is only executed at once
                {
                    if (Work.Count == 0) // if there is no items in the stack return
                        return;

                    Work.Pop()(); // get the last item in the stack and execute it


                    // remove the bottom of the stack by poping everything exept the top item
                    Action temp=null;
                    if(Work.Count>0)
                        temp = Work.Pop();

                    while (Work.Count > 0)
                        Work.Pop();

                    if (temp != null)
                        Work.Push(temp);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

and I can use that class as:

```
        string[] simulationOfTyping = new string[] { "H", "He", "Hel", "Hell", "Hello", "Hello ", "Hello W", "Hello Wo", "Hello Wor", "Hello Worl", "Hello World" };

        // simulate user typing
        foreach(var text in simulationOfTyping)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            DoWorkOnce.Add(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(text);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            });
        }

        // the last item should execute always.
```

Comment: You probably want to run on `TextChanged` and only if no previous thread has been started in the last, say, `300 ms` to stop generating so many requests at once.

Comment: If I do that let's say I type 'Hello' quick. the 'H' part gets executed because there are no threads executing. then threads 'He', 'Hel', ... 'Hello' will not be executed... and most important the one I am interested on 'Hello' will no execute. Hope I understand what you said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from mellamokb's comment, it sounds like you don't really want a thread *pool* at all - you want a *single* thread, with a *single* "next task to execute" - where if there's already a task to execute, it's overwritten by the new one. Essentially like a producer/consumer queue, but with only one "slot" which is overwritten.

Comment: Jon Skeet can you show a short example on how I will be able to override the task. What if the task that I am overriding is executing... I am having trouble making what you said into code...

Answer (score 0):

In TPL Dataflow, this is exactly what [`BroadcastBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160447%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does: it will always remember only the last item posted to it. If you link it to an `ActionBlock` with capacity bounded to 1, that `ActionBlock`'s action will execute the way you want.

Although it probably doesn't make much sense to use TPL Dataflow just for this.